# Can I create a file on Android similar to Windows that reads and processes commands?

Tags: applications, terminal

In Windows, it is possible to use a "bat" file format that reads and processes written commands, such as a command to open the Windows Calculator (which you can also do via CMD).

Is this also possible on Android? If yes, which app and which Android command library can I use?

Comment: Try [Termux](https://termux.com/) app. Read about it. Try it. Keep trying it. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android is a linux-based Operating System, it would be shell scripts (.sh) instead of batch files, probabiy run with sh, a bash like shell located in /system/bin/sh

To open applications using a shell script you <s>would need root access and</s> can use a terminal emulator like [termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/).

First of all, grant termux full storage rights

```
termux-setup-storage
```

To launch apps, you must write commands using [Activity Manager](http://adbcommand.com/adbshell/am)

For instance, to launch calculater (I'm using Google Calculator for the guide) using a shell script in android, the procedure would be this

1. Create a file eg calc.sh in /storage/emulated/0 ie the user-accessible part of your internal storage, with the following content

```
#!/system/bin/sh  
am start com.google.android.calculator/com.android.calculator2.Calculator
```

2. Open Termux

```
cd /storage/emulated/0  
sh calc.sh
```

3. The calculator should launch

Bonus: You can also execute commands on android using your PC via [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)

Answer (score 0):

Use a terminal emulator like [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) to run [shell scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script).